# Ruby file new and open hanging in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: ruby, multithreading, aptana

Why do these two separate commands hang when ran on aptana Studio 3?

1:

```
File.new(path,'r') if not File.exists?(path)
```

2:

```
File.open(path,'r') do |f|
  puts f
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first command, you're trying to open a non-existant file for reading. That command should be throwing an error such as `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`

In your second command, you're trying to open a file, and my guess is the file does not exist, so Ruby should be throwing a similar error.

Perhaps Aptana is catching these errors, so you aren't seeing them? Or perhaps you have a begin...rescue somewhere in your code that is swallowing these errors?

My hunch is you want to change `'r'` to `'w'` in your first command, so you can write to a new file.

Comment: I think you could be right that Aptana is catching the error. Can I make Aptana not catch the error?

Comment: I presume there's a way to have Aptana skip the errors, or at least report them to you. That said, it's much wiser to catch the error in your own code by wrapping your code with a begin...rescue block. This lets you do something reasonable for the user, such as prompting for a different path, or at least advising the user.